# Plotting a ratio $G(s) = \frac{Y(s)}{X(s)}$ with an impulse input on MATLAB

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, matlab

I am trying to simulate a system as such.

$G(s) = \frac{Y(s)}{X(s)}$

such that $G(s) = \frac{s^3 + 4s^2 +6s+8}{s^3 + 3s^2 +5s}$

With an impulse input of $sin(t)$

I am trying to do this in Matlab and was going about it in the following way[image: Matlab Code][image]

In the code I get up to LINE 91 before an error occurs as it can't compute a Laplace of the equation. I am unaware how to fix this and get past my errors. Is there an easier way of doing this?

**I have also provided what I am trying to answer as further clarification towards the problem.**

$ \dddot y + 3\ddot y +5\dot y = \dddot x+4\ddot x +6\dot x +8x $

Find $G(s) = \frac{Y(s)}{X(s)}$, when all initial conditions are zero.

when  $x(t)=\delta(t)$, what is  $y(t)$ as t $\implies \infty$

Plot the simulation (I am using Matlab).

Any help would be appreciated as I am now confusing myself in my own working.

Link to my other question involving the same problem: [Laplace Transform: Find Ratio $G(s)$ and value of $y(t)$ as $t\to \infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3635970/laplace-transform-find-ratio-gs-and-value-of-yt-as-t-to-infty)

Comment: Is the impulse input $x(t)=\sin(t)$ or the cut-off version $x(t)=\theta(t)\sin(t)$ where $\theta$ is the unit ramp or Heaviside function?

Comment: I am unsure as to what you mean. I assumed the impulse input to be $x(t) = \delta (t) = sin(t)$. I am quite new to learning this and am struggling to wrap my head around it. All I can seem to find so far is the ratio $G(s)$ but am unable to go much further. I am also trying to find $y(t)$ in regards to the final value theorem but am struggling.

Comment: How does that make sense to you? The delta is a quite spiky distribution and the sine a quite bounded continuous function, they do not have anything in common, so they can't be equal.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a staggered first-order system for this equation requiring no derivative of the input $x$ as
\begin{align}
y&=u_0+x,& \implies u_0'''+3u_0''+5u_0'&=x''+x'+8x,
\\
u_0'&=u_1+x,& \implies u_1''+3u_1'+5u_1&=-2x'+3x,
\\
u_1'&=u_2-2x,& \implies u_2'+3u_2+5u_1&=9x
\\
u_2'&=-3u_2-5u_1+9x.
\end{align}

This now can be symbolically or numerically solved.

For $x=\delta$ the system simplifies for $t>0$ to
\begin{align}
y&=u_0,& y_0(0)&\text{ does not exist}
\\
u_0'&=u_1,& u_0(0^+)&=1
\\
u_1'&=u_2,& u_1(0^+)&=-2
\\
u_2'&=-3u_2-5u_1, &u_2(0^+)&=9.
\end{align}
[image]

For $x(t)=\theta(t)\sin(t)$, $\theta(t)=0$ for $t<0$ and $=1$ for $t>0$, the right sides of the system are regular, so a differentiable solution exists for $u_0$, $y$ is not differentiable at $t=0$. This means that the first order system has initial conditions equal to zero.

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
def x(t): return sin(maximum(0,t))
def u_fun(u,t): xt=x(t); return [ u[1]+xt, u[2]-2*xt, -3*u[2]-5*u[1]+9*xt]
t=linspace(-1,20,301)
u = odeint(u_fun, [0,0,0], t)
plot(t,u[:,0],':r',label='$u_0(t)$')
plot(t,u[:,0]+x(t),'b',label='$y(t)$')
```

Comment: Whilst I am beginning to understand further about the problem, I think much of my information given was wrong and as such has led to my confusion so apologies, but also thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you are allowed to use the Control System Toolbox, you can do the following:

```
g= tf([1 4 6 8],[1 3 5 0]);
t= 0:0.1:20;
lsim(g,sin(t),t);
figure
impulse(g)
```

This code produces the pictures:

[image: u=sin(t)]
[image: impulse response]

Comment: I believe this is exactly what I was after. I have only one further query, I am trying to calculate my final value for $y(t)$, through use of the theorem. Working below as; $lim s *\frac{s^3+4s^2+6s+8}{s^3+3s^2+5s}$ = $lim s *\frac{s^3+4s^2+6s+8}{(s)s^2+3s+5}$ = $y(t) \implies \infty = \frac{8}{5}$. However, I am unsure if this is the final value of $y(t)$ or the ratio $G(s)$ as a whole. If its correct as $\frac{8}{5}$, how can I compare this in agreement with the plot obtained from Matlab involving the impulse above. Apologies if wordy, hope I get across all relevant information.

Comment: @N.Jon : I decomposed the fraction in my answer [to your first question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3635970/115115). The terms of it translate back to $$\delta(t)+\frac85\theta(t)+e^{-\frac32t}(\sin+\cos).$$ The plot added to my answer illustrates that.

Comment: @N.Jon  I don't see any contradictions here. $\frac85$ is equal to $1.6$, what matches the picture exactly

Comment: Thank you both, this has been incredibly helpful